# ¿Cómo determinar en qué parámetro pasa cada variable en una llamada a un Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Les consulto por una llamada a un `Stored Procedure`, y la verdad no se si es permitido en `SQL` el tipo de paso de los siguientes parámetros, que no puedo comprender, ¿alguno me puede ayudar?:

**llamada al SP:**

```
exec sp_ejecutar @lista1, ',', @lista1 output, @id output
```

**SP que recibe el llamado:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ejecutar @cadena LISTA_DE_CADENA, @divisor char(1), @derecha LISTA_DE_CADENA output, @id int output as
```

Está muy confuso, ya que el SP que envía parámetros repite la variable `@lista1` al hacer el `exec`, ¿por qué?

¿Se podría decir que `@cadena` es igual a `@divisor`?

```
@lista1 = @cadena
',' = divisor
@lista1 = @divisor
@lista2 = id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransactSQL no es diferente de otros lenguajes, en este caso, los parámetros se pasan **en orden** a la rutina que se llama, en otras palabras, con esta declaración:

```
dbo.sp_ejecutar @cadena LISTA_DE_CADENA, @divisor char(1), @derecha LISTA_DE_CADENA output, @id int output as
```

El procedimiento almacenado espera cuatro parámetros, declarados con un nombre y su tipo:

- `@cadena`, de tipo `LISTA_DE_CADENA`
- `@divisor`, de tipo `char(1)`
- `@derecha`, de tipo `LISTA_DE_CADENA`, que además es un parámetro de salida, definido por el *modificador*  `output`
- `@id`, de tipo `int`, también `output`

Cuando se llama:

```
exec sp_ejecutar @lista1, ',', @lista1 output, @id output
```

- `@lista1` se pasa al parámetro `@cadena`
- `','` se pasa al parámetro `@divisor`
- `@lista1` se pasa al parámetro `@derecha` y se indica que se espera una salida con el *modificador*  `output`
- `@id` se pasa al parámetro `@id`, también `output`.

Sobre que se repita la variable `@lista1` en dos parámetros de la salida, el único que puede responder a tu pregunta de por qué, es quién haya escrito esa rutina.

Lo que yo puedo decir es

- en TransactSQL como en prácticamente todos los lenguajes que conozco, es perfectamente normal pasar una misma variable varias veces a una rutina, no tiene nada de particular o de extraño.
- `@Lista1`, luego de la llamada, probablemente cambiará de valor, ya que la segunda vez que se pasa, es como parámetro de salida, con lo que recogerá algún resultado dado por el procedimiento almacenado. (cosa que también es perfectamente normal).

Si esto te parece confuso, SQL Server soporta, dentro de la llamada, indicar el nombre de cada parámetro que pasas, con lo que podrías cambiar la llamada a:

```
exec sp_ejecutar @cadena = @lista1, @divisor = ',', @derecha = @lista1 output, @id = @id output
```

Es muy verboso para mi gusto, pero veo que muchas personas lo utilizan con frecuencia.

Comment: Excelente tu manera de explicarlo, y es asi como comentas, es muy verboso, pero es un poco porque el codigo esta hecho hace mucho. Gracias!